# KerasRegressor Grid Search to optimize hidden layers & number of neurons

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I tried to optimize the number of hidden layers and number of neurons in a Keras Sequential model, along with the batch size and number of epochs. The code for epochs and batch size works, but I keep running into an error when attempting to optimize the hidden layers and number of neurons in each layer. Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer, StandardScaler
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import InputLayer, Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, RandomizedSearchCV
from scipy.stats import randint as sp_randint
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, make_scorer

'''CREATE THE MODEL'''
def design_model(features, activation = 'relu', hidden_layers=2, number_neurons=128):
    model = Sequential(name = "My_Sequential_Model")
    model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(features.shape[1],)))
    for i in range(hidden_layers): 
        model.add(Dense(number_neurons, activation=activation))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
    model.compile(loss='mse', metrics=['mae'], optimizer=opt)
    return model

'''OPTIMIZE THE MODEL: GRID SEARCH'''
def do_grid_search():
    model = KerasRegressor(model=design_model, features=features_train) # KerasRegressor expects a function and not the model
    param_grid = dict(batch_size=[6, 64], epochs=[10, 30, 61], hidden_layers=[1, 2, 3], number_neurons=[64, 128])
    grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = model, param_grid=param_grid, scoring = make_scorer(mean_squared_error, greater_is_better=False), return_train_score=True)
    grid_result = grid.fit(features_train, labels_train, verbose = 0)
    print(f"GRID SEARCH => Best: {grid_result.best_score_} using {grid_result.best_params_}")
    return grid_result.best_params_

best_params = do_grid_search()
```

This is the error I keep running into:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter hidden_layers for estimator KerasRegressor.
This issue can likely be resolved by setting this parameter in the KerasRegressor constructor:
`KerasRegressor(hidden_layers=1)`
Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`
```

What do I do?

Comment: I didn't test it yet, but it could be that you have to give the keys in `param_grid` as strings (like `"epochs"=[10, 30, 61]`).